# How to delete user in asp.net identity 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

As mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx) In 1.0, if you had to delete a User, you could not do it through the UserManager and it's fixed in release 2.0 so we can do the following to delete a user:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
if (user == null)
{
   return HttpNotFound();
}
var result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: **"it doesn't work"**, what do you mean by this? is there an error?

Comment: Also, are you definitely using this version `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 2.0.0-alpha1`?

Comment: @christiandev no error, it's just not working (without any error). I used nuget to update from 1.0 to 2.0

Comment: I had this problem as well. My issue was that I was not awaiting the async call to my method with code similar to yours. This was in an ASP.NET Web API project, and the framework apparently swallows non-awaited async method calls :/.

Answer (score 0):

```
var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

   if (um.IsInRole(formCollection["user"], role))

      {

        um.RemoveFromRole(formCollection["user"], role);

     }

using RemoveFromRole function and pass (userid ,rolename);
```